# Python - "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Tags: python, pandas

As the first step of a larger process, I'm trying to get the column names from some .dat files.  I'm getting the `"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:" error`, but I'm passing it the directory path and it is telling me the first file in the folder, so it doesn't seem to be the usual suspect of the relative/absolute path issue.

```
dir_path = "C:/Projects/acs5-2022/Datasource/TestSample"

column_list = []

for path, subs, file_names in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in file_names:
        datafile = pandas.read_csv(file, delimiter='|')
        for col in datafile.columns:
            col.append(column_list)

print(column_list)
```

And I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'acsdt5y2022-b02009.dat'
```

`acsdt5y2022-b02009.dat` is the first file in the `TestSample` folder.  I'm not giving it that information, so it can, in fact, see the files.

The header in this particular file is `GEO_ID|B02009_E001|B02009_M001`

I've tried various formats for the path directory - `"C:/.....", r"C:\.....", "C:\\....."` - it doesn't seem to matter.

Any suggestions?  Is it the .dat format?  Is it the pipes?  I'm using PyCharm and I've seen some posts on that, but again, I'm specifying the directory.

Thank you in advance for any direction you can give me!

Comment: `file` is only the bare filename.  It does not include the directory path.

Comment: Thank you, toyota Supra, for making my question easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `os.walk()` gets the absolute correct path and returns the `path`, `subs`, and `file_names`. However, when calling the `read_csv()` function, you are only passing the file (file name) relative to the current folder. In order for pandas to access this file, it needs a full path, as found in `os.walk()`. To do this, simply change `read_csv(file)` to `read_csv(os.path.join(path, file))`, where the `join()` method of `os.path` includes the path and filename are combined, forming a absolute address.

Another issue I noticed in your code is the following.

```
for col in datafile.columns:
    col.append(column_list)
```

You're trying to add the column name to a list of columns, but you're actually adding a list of columns to a column. It should be:

```
for col in datafile.columns:
   column_list.append(col)
```

the final code:

```
import os
import pandas

dir_path = "C:/Projects/acs5-2022/Datasource/TestSample"

column_list = []

for path, subs, file_names in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in file_names:
        datafile = pandas.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file), delimiter='|')
        for col in datafile.columns:
            column_list.append(col)

print(column_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

`file_names` is only the filename without the path. `read_csv()` requires the full filename including the path. The path is returned in the `path` variable. You need to join them via `os.path.join()`

So:

```
dir_path = "C:/Projects/acs5-2022/Datasource/TestSample"

column_list = []

for path, subs, file_names in os.walk(dir_path): 
    for file in file_names: 
        full_file_path = os.join(path, file)
        datafile = pandas.read_csv(full_file_path, delimiter='|') 
    for col in datafile.columns: column_list.append(col)

print(column_list)
```

should work.

Edit: Solution now also includes appending `col` to `column_list` (as opposed to the other way around) as pointed out by Micael Muniz in his anwser.